# Matching binaries in Erlang

Tags: erlang

For example:

```
<<Sync:11,B:2,C:2,D:1>> = <<2#1111111111101011>>.
** exception error: no match of right hand side value
```

Why? I think variable Sync must be 2#11111111111 but it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it will work if you will specify number of bits in right hand side

```
<<Sync:11,B:2,C:2,D:1>> = <<2#1111111111101011:16>>.
```

Comment: The default size of an integer segment is 8 bits, irrespective of the size of the integer. That is why you must give size in this case to get 16 bits.